# laravel-elixir Causing `npm install` to Error and cannot run `gulp`

Tags: node.js, laravel, gulp

I am having an issue with adding `laravel-elixir` to my `package.json` file in order to run `gulp`. When I run the command `$ gulp` i receive an error stating that laravel-elixir module cannot be found. So, adding the module to my package.json file then running `npm install` causes an error. (`npm install` works fine without the laravel-elixir module in package.json)

I have read through all the documentation and have ensured everything is installed. This seems to be a bit of an issue from what i have researched (sorry in advanced if this might be a dublicate). I just cannot seem to find the fix here. Please comment and let me know if you need to see the errors or anything.

package.json

```
{
"private": true,
"devDependencies": {
"gulp": "^3.9.1",
"gulp-bower": "0.0.13",
"run-sequence": "^1.2.2",
"babel-cli": "^6.7.7",
"babel-preset-es2015": "^6.9.0",
"chai": "^3.5.0",
"laravel-elixir-browserify-official": "^0.1.3",
"laravel-elixir-coffeescript": "^1.0.2",
"laravel-elixir-rollup-official": "^1.0.4",
"laravel-elixir-stylus": "^2.0.2",
"laravel-elixir-vue": "^0.1.4",
"laravel-elixir-webpack-official": "^1.0.1",
"mocha": "^2.4.5",
"rimraf": "^2.5.2",
"laravel-elixir": "^4.0.0"
},
"dependencies": {
"babel-preset-es2015": "^6.24.1",
"babel-preset-react": "^6.24.1",
"es2015": "0.0.0",
"gulp-install": "^1.1.0",
"react": "^0.14.6",
"vue": "^1.0.28",
"vue-resource": "^0.5.1",
"vue-router": "^0.7.13",
"vue-validator": "^2.1.7",
"gulp-coffee": "^2.3.1",
"clean-css": "^3.4.12",
"cli-table": "^0.3.1",
"del": "^2.2.0",
"glob": "^7.0.3",
"gulp-autoprefixer": "^3.1.0",
"gulp-batch": "^1.0.5",
"gulp-concat": "^2.6.0",
"gulp-if": "^2.0.0",
"gulp-less": "^3.0.5",
"gulp-load-plugins": "^1.2.2",
"gulp-notify": "^2.2.0",
"gulp-rename": "^1.2.2",
"gulp-rev": "^7.0.0",
"gulp-rev-replace": "^0.4.3",
"gulp-sass": "^3.1.0",
"gulp-shell": "^0.5.2",
"gulp-sourcemaps": "^1.6.0",
"gulp-uglify": "^1.5.3",
"gulp-util": "^3.0.7",
"parse-filepath": "^1.0.1",
"path": "^0.12.7",
"q": "^1.4.1",
"require-dir": "^0.3.2",
"run-sequence": "^1.1.5",
"underscore": "^1.8.3",
"vinyl-map2": "^1.2.1"
}
}
```

Gulp File

```
var gulp = require("gulp");
var bower = require("gulp-bower");
var elixir = require("laravel-elixir");

gulp.task('bower', function () {
return bower();
});
/*
 |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
 | Elixir Asset Management
 |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
 */
var vendors = '../../../bower_components/';

var paths = {
'jquery': vendors + 'jquery/dist',
'jqueryUi': vendors + 'jquery-ui',
'moment': vendors + 'moment',
'bootstrap': vendors + 'bootstrap/dist',
'dataTables': vendors + 'datatables/media',
'jquerycookie': vendors + 'jquery.cookie',
'fontawesome': vendors + 'font-awesome',
'animate': vendors + 'animate.css',
'underscore': vendors + 'underscore',
'tether': vendors + 'tether/dist',
'jQueryStorageAPI': vendors + 'jQuery-Storage-API',
'pace': vendors + 'PACE',
'lazyload': vendors + 'lazyload',
'screenfull': vendors + 'screenfull/dist',
'select2': vendors + 'select2/dist',
'select2TabFix': vendors + 'select2-tab-fix',
'eonasdanBootstrapDatetimepicker': vendors + 'eonasdan-bootstrap-datetimepicker/build',
'fullcalendar': vendors + 'fullcalendar/dist',
'summernote': vendors + 'summernote/dist',
'morris': vendors + 'morris.js',
'raphael': vendors + 'raphael',
'algoliasearch': vendors + 'algoliasearch/dist/',
'algoliaAutocomplete': vendors + 'algolia-autocomplete.js/dist/',
'typeahead': vendors + 'typeahead.js/dist/',
'pusher': vendors + 'pusher/dist/',
'icheck': vendors + 'iCheck',
'jasnyBootstrap': vendors + 'jasny-bootstrap/dist',
'toastr': vendors + 'toastr/',
'dropzone': vendors + 'dropzone/dist',
'select2BootstrapTheme': vendors + 'select2-bootstrap-theme/dist',
'c3': vendors + '/c3/'
};

elixir.config.sourcemaps = false;

elixir(function (mix) {

// Run bower install
mix.task('bower');

//Custom Styles
mix.styles(
    [
       'lcrm_bootstrap.css', 'metisMenu.min.css', 'lcrm.css', 'mail.css'
    ], 'public/css/secure.css');

//Custom Javascript
mix.browserify(['app.js'], 'public/js/secure.js');


/**
 * Vendor files
 * run "gulp --production"
 */
if (elixir.config.production) {
    // Copy js straight to public
    mix.copy('resources/assets/js/metisMenu.min.js', 'public/js');
    mix.copy('resources/assets/js/datetime-moment.js', 'public/js');
    mix.copy('resources/assets/js/lcrm_app.js', 'public/js');
    mix.copy('resources/assets/js/todolist.js', 'public/js');

    // Copy fonts straight to public
    mix.copy('bower_components/bootstrap/fonts', 'public/fonts/bootstrap');
    mix.copy('bower_components/font-awesome/fonts', 'public/fonts');
    mix.copy('resources/assets/css/material-design-icons/iconfont', 'public/fonts');

    // Copy images straight to public
    mix.copy('bower_components/bootstrap-fileinput/img', 'public/img');
    mix.copy('bower_components/jquery-ui/themes/base/images', 'public/img');
    mix.copy('bower_components/datatables/media/images', 'public/img');

    mix.copy('resources/assets/img', 'public/img');
    mix.copy('resources/assets/images', 'public/images');
    mix.copy('resources/assets/img/logo.png', 'public/uploads/site');
    mix.copy('resources/assets/img/fav.ico', 'public/uploads/site');
    mix.copy('resources/assets/img/user.png', 'public/uploads/avatar');

    // copy js files ( we don't need to combine all files into single js)
    mix.copy('bower_components/screenfull/dist/screenfull.min.js', 'public/js');

    //c3&d3 chart css and js files
    mix.copy('bower_components/c3/c3.min.css', 'public/css');
    mix.copy('bower_components/c3/c3.min.js', 'public/js');
    mix.copy('bower_components/d3/d3.min.js', 'public/js');
    mix.copy('resources/assets/js/d3.v3.min.js', 'public/js');

    //jvector map files
    mix.copy('bower_components/bower-jvectormap/jquery-jvectormap-1.2.2.min.js', 'public/js');
    mix.copy('resources/assets/css/jquery-jvectormap.css', 'public/css');
    mix.copy('resources/assets/js/jquery-jvectormap-us-aea-en.js', 'public/js');

    //icheck
    mix.copy('resources/assets/css/icheck.css','public/css');
    mix.copy('bower_components/iCheck/icheck.min.js','public/js');

    //countUp
    mix.copy('bower_components/countUp.js/dist/countUp.min.js', 'public/js');

    //jQuery Sortable
    mix.copy('resources/assets/js/jquery-sortable.js', 'public/js');
    //CSS Libraries
    mix.styles([paths.fontawesome + "/css/font-awesome.min.css",
        paths.animate + "/animate.min.css",
        "resources/assets/css/material-design-icons/material-design-icons.css",
        paths.select2 + "/css/select2.min.css",
        paths.eonasdanBootstrapDatetimepicker + '/css/bootstrap-datetimepicker.css',
        'dataTables.bootstrap.css',
        paths.fullcalendar + '/fullcalendar.css',
        paths.summernote + '/summernote.css',
        paths.summernote + '/summernote-bs3.css',
        paths.morris + '/morris.css',
        paths.dropzone + '/dropzone.css',
        paths.jasnyBootstrap + "/css/jasny-bootstrap.min.css",
        paths.toastr + '/toastr.css',
        paths.select2BootstrapTheme + "/select2-bootstrap.min.css"
    ], 'public/css/libs.css');


    //JS Libraries
    mix.scripts([paths.jquery + "/jquery.js",
        paths.jqueryUi + "/jquery-ui.min.js",
        paths.tether + "/js/tether.min.js",
        paths.bootstrap + "/js/bootstrap.min.js",
        paths.dataTables + "/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js",
        paths.dataTables + "/js/dataTables.bootstrap.js",
        paths.jquerycookie + "/jquery.cookie.js",
        paths.pace + '/pace.min.js',
        paths.underscore + "/underscore-min.js",
        paths.select2 + "/js/select2.min.js",
        paths.select2TabFix + "/src/select2-tab-fix.min.js",
        paths.moment + '/moment.js',
        paths.eonasdanBootstrapDatetimepicker + '/js/bootstrap-datetimepicker.min.js',
        paths.fullcalendar + '/fullcalendar.js',
        paths.summernote + '/summernote.js',
        paths.morris + '/morris.js',
        paths.raphael + '/raphael.js',
        paths.algoliasearch + '/algoliasearch.min.js',
        paths.algoliaAutocomplete + '/autocomplete.min.js',
        paths.typeahead + '/typeahead.jquery.min.js',
        paths.pusher + '/pusher.js',
        paths.toastr + 'toastr.min.js',
        paths.jasnyBootstrap +  "/js/jasny-bootstrap.min.js",

        "palette.js"
    ], 'public/js/libs.js');
}
});
```

Error

```
npm install
npm WARN deprecated minimatch@1.0.0: Please update to minimatch 3.0.2 or higher to avoid a RegExp DoS issue

> node-sass@3.13.1 install C:\xampp\htdocs\trinet\node_modules\laravel-elixir\node_modules\node-sass
> node scripts/install.js

Downloading binary from https://github.com/sass/node-sass/releases/download/v3.13.1/win32-x64-57_binding.node
Cannot download "https://github.com/sass/node-sass/releases/download/v3.13.1/win32-x64-57_binding.node":

HTTP error 404 Not Found

Hint: If github.com is not accessible in your location
  try setting a proxy via HTTP_PROXY, e.g.

  export HTTP_PROXY=http://example.com:1234

or configure npm proxy via

  npm config set proxy http://example.com:8080

> uws@9.14.0 install C:\xampp\htdocs\trinet\node_modules\uws
> node-gyp rebuild > build_log.txt 2>&1 || exit 0


> node-sass@3.13.1 postinstall C:\xampp\htdocs\trinet\node_modules\laravel-elixir\node_modules\node-sass
> node scripts/build.js

Building: C:\Program Files\nodejs\node.exe 
C:\xampp\htdocs\trinet\node_modules\node-gyp\bin\node-gyp.js rebuild --          
verbose --libsass_ext= --libsass_cflags= --lib                                                                             
sass_ldflags= --libsass_library=
gyp info it worked if it ends with ok
gyp verb cli [ 'C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe',
gyp verb cli   'C:\\xampp\\htdocs\\trinet\\node_modules\\node- 
gyp\\bin\\node-gyp.js',
gyp verb cli   'rebuild',
gyp verb cli   '--verbose',
gyp verb cli   '--libsass_ext=',
gyp verb cli   '--libsass_cflags=',
gyp verb cli   '--libsass_ldflags=',
gyp verb cli   '--libsass_library=' ]
gyp info using node-gyp@3.6.2
    gyp info using node@8.11.1 | win32 | x64
    gyp verb command rebuild []
    gyp verb command clean []
    gyp verb clean removing "build" directory
    gyp verb command configure []
    gyp verb check python checking for Python executable 
    "C:/Users/user/AppData/Local/Programs/Python/Python37/python.exe" in the PATH
    gyp verb `which` succeeded 
    C:/Users/user/AppData/Local/Programs/Python/Python37/python.exe 
    C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\python.exe
    gyp verb check python version 
    `C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\python.exe -c "import platform; print(platform.python_version());"` retur                                                                             ned: "3.7.0b3\r\n"
gyp verb could not find "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\python.exe". checking python launcher
gyp verb could not find "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\python.exe". guessing location
gyp verb ensuring that file exists: C:\Python27\python.exe
gyp ERR! configure error
gyp ERR! stack Error: Can't find Python executable "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\python.exe", you can set the PYTHON env variable.
gyp ERR! stack     at PythonFinder.failNoPython (C:\xampp\htdocs\trinet\node_modules\node-gyp\lib\configure.js:483:19)
gyp ERR! stack     at PythonFinder.<anonymous> (C:\xampp\htdocs\trinet\node_modules\node-gyp\lib\configure.js:508:16)
gyp ERR! stack     at C:\xampp\htdocs\trinet\node_modules\node-gyp\node_modules\graceful-fs\polyfills.js:284:29
gyp ERR! stack     at FSReqWrap.oncomplete (fs.js:152:21)
gyp ERR! System Windows_NT 10.0.16299
gyp ERR! command "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe" "C:\\xampp\\htdocs\\trinet\\node_modules\\node-gyp\\bin\\node-gyp.js" "rebuild" "--verbose" "--libsass_ex                                                                             t=" "--libsass_cflags=" "--libsass_ldflags=" "--libsass_library="
gyp ERR! cwd C:\xampp\htdocs\trinet\node_modules\laravel-elixir\node_modules\node-sass
gyp ERR! node -v v8.11.1
gyp ERR! node-gyp -v v3.6.2
gyp ERR! not ok
Build failed with error code: 1
npm WARN buble-loader@0.2.2 requires a peer of buble@^0.12.0 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN vue-template-validator@1.1.5 requires a peer of parse5@^2.1.0 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN The package run-sequence is included as both a dev and production dependency.
npm WARN The package babel-preset-es2015 is included as both a dev and production dependency.
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: fsevents@1.1.3 (node_modules\fsevents):
npm WARN notsup SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Unsupported platform for fsevents@1.1.3: wanted {"os":"darwin","arch":"any"} (current: {"os":"win32","arch":"x64"}                                                                             )

npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! node-sass@3.13.1 postinstall: `node scripts/build.js`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the node-sass@3.13.1 postinstall script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.
```

Comment: can i see the packages.json with laravel-elixir?

Comment: @SupunPraneeth I have added the contents of the package.json

Comment: `package.json` file is okay, and it's installed fine

Comment: can i see your gulp.js ?

Comment: @SupunPraneeth the `gulpfile.js` file? correct?

Comment: Yes, i've forgot

Comment: @SupunPraneeth I have added the contents of the file.

Comment: @OluwafemiSule I added the error that `npm install` returned

Comment: You're missing a required python installation. Do that and lets see what else may be missing

Comment: OK i found the error. I think it kinda bug. elixir somehow require  node-sass v3.1 but it'z removed from the GitHub. run this and see whether its working:

Comment: {"private": true,"devDependencies": {"run-sequence": "^1.2.2","laravel-elixir": "*"},"dependencies": {"babel-preset-es2015": "^6.24.1","babel-preset-react": "^6.24.1",
"es2015": "0.0.0","gulp-install": "^1.1.0","react": "^0.14.6",
"vue": "^1.0.28","vue-resource": "^0.5.1","vue-router": "^0.7.13",
"vue-validator": "^2.1.7","gulp-coffee": "^2.3.1","clean-css": "^3.4.12","cli-table": "^0.3.1","del": "^2.2.0","glob": "^7.0.3","parse-filepath": "^1.0.1","path": "^0.12.7","q": "^1.4.1","require-dir": "^0.3.2","run-sequence": "^1.1.5","underscore": "^1.8.3","vinyl-map2": "^1.2.1"}}

Comment: @SupunPraneeth thanks but that chunk did not work for me. I did install node-sass but unfortunately i am still receiving the same errors

Comment: oh yeah, it's not working for windows but for linux, I've tried with win and it didn't work me either. you have few options, either you have to use linux or use gulp without elixer or use new laravel mix

Comment: or give it a try installing python  https://www.python.org/downloads/windows/

Comment: @SupunPraneeth Python was my issue. I had it downloaded but like Oluwafemi suggested, i did not have it in my PATH variable... OOPS

Comment: @SupunPraneeth even though my site loaded after the python was added to the PATH i am still unable to get laravel-elixir to install and am unable to execute `gulp --production`

Comment: Have run npm install after python was added to the path?

Answer (score 0):

Try installing python first , since it is searching for the executable and unable to find it